# React - redux - firebase application testing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I have an almost completed react application with firestore database as the backend. I need to perform testing on my application and I haven't done any software testing before. How can I perform testing on my application? Are there any sources available for me to refer to? 
I need to test my backend as well. Including firebase authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at firebase docs regarding testing possibilities on the platform.

With firebase basically you have [Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) for kind of integration and end to end testing and having most fundamental firebase services (Firestore, Functions, Hosting) being run locally on your machine, and also [functions shell](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing) to unit testing your functions with mock data.